# How to make this first-not-null-result function more elegant/concise?

Tags: scala

getFirstNotNullResult executes a list of functions, until one of them returns a not null value.
How to implement getNotNullFirstResult more elegantly/concise?

```
object A {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(test());
  }

  def test(): String = {
    getFirstNotNullResult(f1 _ :: f2 _ :: f3 _ :: Nil);
  }

  def getFirstNotNullResult(fs: List[() => String]): String = {
    fs match {
      case head::tail => 
        val v = head(); 
        if (v != null) return v;
        return getFirstNotNullResult(tail);

      case Nil => null
    }
  }

  // these would be some complex and slow functions; we only want to execute them if necessary; that is, if f1() returns not null, we don't want to execute f2 nor f3.
  def f1(): String = { null }
  def f2(): String = { "hello" }
  def f3(): String = { null }
}
```

Comment: hi, the three answers are excellent, thanks! i am sorry that stackoverflow only allows me to accept one.

Comment: In future, we have a sister site for this:  [codereview.se].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def getFirstNN(fs: List[() => String]): String = fs.iterator.map(_()).find(_ ne null).get
```

Comment: Are really needed `iterator` and `map`? Why not just `fs.find(_() != null)`?

Comment: @jglatre - That would pass back the function that returns a non-null value, not the value that the function computed.

Comment: thanks! now I see... but, `map` will evaluate all functions, even unneeded ones, isn't so?

Comment: @jglatre - That's why the `iterator` is used.  It will evaluate as it iterates (stopping as soon as it finds something).

Comment: hmmm, nice! I'll check it in the console.

Answer (score 11):

I like Rex's answer, but your question brings up so many things, I'd like to expand on it, to add:

1. Using Scala's [Option/Some/None](http://www.tuple23.com/2010/10/scalas-option-will-save-you-from-most.html) classes to clarify what should be returned when no match is found.  Your example returned null, Rex's threw an exception.  Using Option makes it immediately clear that we will return a match or "None".
2. Use type parameters so you don't have to operate just on functions that return a String.

Here's the code:

```
object A extends App {
def getFirstNNWithOption[T](fs: List[() => Option[T]]): Option[T] = fs
    .view //allows us to evaluate your functions lazily: only evaluate as many as it takes to find a match 
    .flatMap(_()) //invoke the function, discarding results that return None
    .headOption // take the first element from the view - returns None if empty

def f1 = { println("f1"); None }
def f2 = Some("yay!")
def f3 = { println("f2"); None }

println(getFirstNNWithOption(List(f1 _, f2 _, f3 _)))
 }
```

Note that when this code runs, f2 never prints, demonstrating that, thanks to the .view call, we evaluate the minimum number of functions before returning a match.

Note that callers of this method now must consider the fact that a match might not be found: instead of returning T, we return Option[T].  In our case above, it would return Some("yay").  When all functions return None, the return value would be None. No more NullPointerExceptions when you mistake a null for an actual match!

Comment: iinm, Rex's code would behave the same as yours if you simply remove `.get` at the end of his code (and change the type signature, of course). Although `Option` is definitely a clearer way to deal with absence of a value than `null`.

Comment: you're correct... i was just expanding on his example to show Option (return value and parameters), flatMap, type params.

Answer (score 5):

You'll probably want the type passed into getFirstNotNullResult to be a Stream[String] instead of List[() => String] and construct it something like:

```
Stream.cons(f1, Stream.cons(f2, Stream.cons(f3, Stream.empty)))
```

Then getFirstNotNullResult changes to be:

```
fs.filter(_ != null).headOption
```

Which will also mean that it should really return Option[String] as well, as you can't guarantee that something will be non-null.

As suggested, the reason why I suggest a Stream is that it only evaluates the "tail" of the Stream on demand. So if getFirstNotNullResult finds that the first element is not null then the second parameter to the first Stream.cons call is never actually executed.

Comment: Good answer, but you should explain why a stream should be used instead of a list.